# 1 Million Polygons

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

So i have this blender project and i subdivided it a lot of times so i could paint it better, but now that i have 1,064,839Tris i cant really do anything. i don't need that many polygons so i tried using things like Decimate but even when i click on Object Mode blender crashes. Blender also crashes when using tools like Decimate so what can i do. My PC is really fast and can run almost all AAA Games and software so my PC is not the problem.

Comment: Explain a bit more in depth what you are trying to do.
It's quite hard to guess what you're going for with limited information.
Also some screenshots or computer specs would help us to give you an answer that is helpful.

Comment: My specs: Intel Pentium g4560, GTX 950, 240GB SSD, and 8GB DDR4 RAM

Comment: i just want the model compressed with less polygons

Comment: Then the decimate modifier is definitely the way to go.
It shouldn't have any trouble with only 1milion polys though.
I'd recommend posting some screenshots or adding a blendfile for testing purposes to your question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1Hrd5PMqmY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCzkOrYWysg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: thats my situation

Comment: I suggest also that you upload your file so that someone else could try to do it if your computer crashes... but also an advice: make copies of your meshes! A question too: is your model only subdivided or was it modified (the mesh part) after the subdivision?

Comment: i think its only subdivided, btw the file is coming

Comment: https://ufile.io/26b6a1

Comment: No problems occurring here when using the decimate modifier. I'm using blender 2.77 at the moment.
Quite slow though.

Comment: could you upload the decimated file so i can use that, that would fix everythin except if its a bug in my blender

Comment: FYI decimate crashes here too (2.78c) using the collapse option. And unsubdivide gives a bad result. And remove doubles crashes too.

Comment: i know, i tried unsubdivide too, but whats the problem then

Comment: btw im using Blender 2.78 on steam

Comment: IMO, there are 2 things in your mesh that Blender do not like: ngons and inverted normals... just an hypothesis

Comment: i don't know what those are but is there a solution to it?

Comment: Here is your file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3115" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3115/). What I've done: separate mesh parts, decimate each part, except the kind of cube which was the cause of the crash. But this is just a cube and you have the same arrow elsewhere in the mesh. I needed to remove the original as giantcowfilms has a limit of 30GB... and FYI I think nearly the same result could have been modeled with around 1k vertices

Comment: Thanks! i changed some things about the model and optimized it to 16000 tris and it still looks the same

Comment: File crashes on my system too. Probably a bug, hard crash like this should not occur, even if the mesh is not "perfect". You should post the file on https://developer.blender.org/ for the devs to debug.

Comment: FYI, this is a stackoverflow exception. But the console does not indicate more than that.

Comment: Its all fixed my sword is ready for use in game engines, if someone wants it ill drop a link:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7w4lqqtibyohoqw/KurikaraParts.blend?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mk48y7cfdk1v1ha/Finished%20Kurikara.blend?dl=0

Comment: here is the update one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjwkk68knl9w3wj/KurikaraParts.blend?dl=0